# Transit at Dammam without leaving the transit area

Tags: transit, saudi-arabia, self-transfer, dmm

I am from the Czech Republic.

I am looking to fly from Phuket to Muscat, Muscat to Dammam with Salam air.

At Dammam I have a layover for 16 hours, to catch a flight to Vienna with Wizz Air.

I will not be checking any bags, I will have just a carry on.

Can I get a boarding pass for my flight from Dammam to Vienna without leaving the transit zone? And if yes, how?

I don't want to pay for evisa just because of a 16 hours layover.

I've also read about transit visas, but some sources say that they are available only for flights with Saudi Airlines or FlyNas.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Remember, if you self-connect, the first airline is very likely to want to see evidence that you can enter the destination country (in this case, Saudi Arabia). In your case this is fine as with your citizenship you can get visa on arrival (so your passport is enough for the airline), but for future readers in different situations, beware.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but as you said, I can get a visa on arrival, so it shouldn't be a problem. Are you trying to say, in the worst case scenario i can always get a visa on arrival? Or are you not answering my question? Thank you.

Comment: It's just a comment for future readers, but indeed, as a worst case you can get the visa on arrival. But since Wizz Air do not allow mobile boarding passes to be issued for that flight, I'm not quite sure how/if you can avoid going through check-in. But someone more familiar with Wizz Air procedures and/or that airport may know more.